# Mongoose document update error

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

Been working with `node` and `mongoose` lately and I enjoyed it until I had to update a model.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
module.exports.update = (post, cb) ->
  Post.update _id: post._id, post, (err, data) ->
    cb(err, data)
```

So I thought it'll be a easy as saving a new post but it's complaining
with error:

> err: 'Mod on _id not allowed'

I tried to delete `post._id` before passing it to my update method, but it didn't work and I
couldn't find any good examples on how to do it except one that looks
a bit odd where first you find `Post` by `_id`, then update each key
manually and save Post back again...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `post` a plain object or a `Post` model instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with deleting `post._id` before passing it to `update`.  Assuming `post` is a plain JS object, this should work:

```
module.exports.update = (post, cb) ->
  id = post._id
  delete post._id
  Post.update _id: id, post, (err, data) ->
    cb(err, data)
```

Comment: Hey I finally got it! Thank you very much :)