# Update a record where _id = :id with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update an existing record with Mongoose. The insert is OK but not the update.

Here is my snippet:

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {

    var my_visit = new models.visits({
        date: req.body.visit_date,
        type: req.body.visit_type,
        agency: req.body.visit_agency,
        city: req.body.visit_city,
        url: req.body.visit_url,
        note: req.body.visit_note
    });

    // INSERT
    if(req.body.id == 0) {
        my_visit.save(function(err) {
            if(err) { throw err; }

            console.log('added visit');

            res.redirect('/');
        });
    } else { // UPDATE
        var upsertData = my_visit.toObject();

        console.log(req.body.id); // OK

        models.visits.update({ _id: req.body.id }, upsertData, { multi: false }, function(err) {
            if(err) { throw err; }

            console.log('updated visit: '+ req.body.id);

            res.redirect('/');
        });
    }


})
```

The response is `Mod on _id is not allowed`.

I just want to update the line such as `WHERE id = id` in MySQL. I didn't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337685/mongoose-js-how-to-implement-create-or-update) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352735/mongoose-document-update-error), the `Mod on _id is not allowed` occurs when one tries to update an object based on its id without deleting it first.

I also found this [github issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/571) which tries to explain a solution. It explicitly states:

> Be careful to not use an existing model instance for the update clause
>   (this won't work and can cause weird behavior like infinite loops).
>   Also, ensure that the update clause does not have an _id property,
>   which causes Mongo to return a "Mod on _id not allowed" error.

The solution, it seems, is to do the following:

```
var upsertData = my_visit.toObject();

console.log(req.body.id); // OK

delete upsertData._id;

models.visits.update({ _id: req.body.id }, upsertData, { multi: false }, function(err) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    //...
}
```

---

On a side note, you can probably rewrite your route to do both the create and update without the if-else clause. [update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) takes an extra option `upsert`, which, according to the docs:

> upsert (boolean) whether to create the doc if it doesn't match (false)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
routes/router.js
router.patch('/user/:id', userController.updateUser)
```

> ```
> exports.updateUser  =  async(req, res) => {
>
>
>
> const  updates  =  Object.keys(req.body)
>
> const  allowedUpdates  = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'age']
>
> const  isValidOperation  =  updates.every((update) =>  allowedUpdates.includes(update))
>
>
>
> if (!isValidOperation) {
>
> return  res.status(400).send('Invalid updates!')
>
> }
>
>
>
> try {
>
> const  user  =  await  UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new:  true, runValidators:  true })
>
>
>
> if (!user) {
>
> return  res.status(404).send()
>
> }
>
>
>
> res.status(201).send(user)
>
> } catch (error) {
>
> res.status(400).send(error)
>
> }
>
> }
> ```