# Issue with Sequelize Query and PUT errors in Chrome

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, sequelize.js

STUDENT QUESTION!

I'm learning about Node.js/Express and MySQL databases using the Sequelize ORM. Traditionally in our simple applications, after querying a MySQL database with Sequelize, we will issue a `res.redirect('/')` within Express PUT route's .then promise, similar to this:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    db.Burgers.create({
      burger_name: req.body.burger_name
    }).then(function () {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

I'm running into a problem when creating a sequelize query using the `findOrCreate()` method. Namely, I'm struggling to find where to place the res.redirect statement on an AJAX PUT request.  For some reason, when I have the res.redirect('/') attached within the express route for the PUT statement, I will see duplicate PUT requests in the Chrome Network inspector.  The first PUT request is displayed as (localhost:3000/devour, type:text/plain, status:302).

[image: the Two PUT requests]

The PUT request is received by the Express server and the sequelize query succeeds, updating the proper tables in the MySQL database. However, the redirect on the Express route does not succeed and Chrome Inpector shows an error " PUT http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)" and when I look at the Network tab I see a second PUT request (localhost:3000/, type:xhr, status:404).

This is the Express PUT route:

```
app.put("/devour", function (req, res) {
var customerId;
// Check to see if the customer name entered already exists, if not create
db.Customers.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    customer_name: req.body.customer_name
  }
})
.spread((user, created) => {
  if (created) console.log("User created");
  customerId = user.id;
  var update = {
    "devoured": req.body.devoured,
    "CustomerId": customerId
  };
  db.Burgers.update(update, {
    where: {
      id: req.body.id
    }
  }).then(function () {
  res.redirect('/');    
});
})
});
```

What is generating this second PUT request?  Is it a response rather than request?

This is my first Sequelize query using the `findOrCreate()` method so perhaps I'm misunderstading the use of .spread().

If I comment out the res.redirect on the PUT Express route, the error does not occur but I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated data from the MySQL database.

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
I added the 303 status code to my Express PUT route:  res.redirect(303, '/').  This elmininated the 404 error on the redirect, however the HTML page was not refreshing with GET request to reload the page with updates from the PUT request.

Then I looked at my Ajax call and realized that, perhaps, I needed to add code there to handle the response from the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)
  })
```

So I added a .done promise callback and the page successfully refreshes following the PUT request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)
  }).done(function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/'
})
```

I guess I'm a bit confused about why the server-side res.redirect(303, '/'), alone, doesn't result in the page refresh on the client-side.  What is the point of providing the '/' path as an argument?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about what a redirect header does when included in PUT requests in [Why POST redirects to GET and PUT redirects to PUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214717/why-post-redirects-to-get-and-put-redirects-to-put)

Long story short your PUT request remains a PUT request, just gets redirected to `/`.

Your app should work properly if you provide 303 status code.

```
res.redirect( 303, '/' );
```

Comment: Thank you for this information!  Adding the 303 status code to the redirect does, indeed, eliminate the 404 error on the redirect request, however it does not have the effect of reloading the page at "/"  (localhost:3000/) which would fire off a GET request to update the database changes onto the screen.

Comment: I did not know that you have Ajax call. The redirect works it's just for the Ajax response, so it is basically useless. By adding it to the promise callback as you did, is the proper way!